# Two orthonormal vectors in space with finite decimal representation

Tags: vector-spaces, orthonormal, decimal-expansion, orthogonality

I'm trying to formulate an exercise related to linear algebra, and for that I need two vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ which

- have unit length,
- are orthogonal to one another,
- don't have any zero coordinates and
- can be represented using short decimal expansions of at most two digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to answering this question lies in the consideration of [Pythagorean quadruples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple). Enumerating (not only primitive) quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$ I looked for those cases where $d=2^m5^n$ for some $m,n\in\{0,1,2\}$, i.e. those where $\frac1d$ has a finite decimal expansion with no more than two decimals. Then for each possible value $d$ I looked at all corresponding triples $(a,b,c)$, trying to find pairs which, for any permutation and any choice of signs, resulted in a zero dot product.

It turns out that, up to permutation and sign changes, there is exactly one such pair with two decimals:

$$
\left\langle\left(\begin{array}{r}0.36\\0.48\\0.80\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r}0.48\\0.64\\-0.60\end{array}\right)\right\rangle=0
$$

If you allow for one more decimal, you get 14 more combinations:

$$
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.024 \\ 0.640 \\ 0.768\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.768 \\ 0.480 \\-0.424\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\qquad
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.024 \\ 0.640 \\ 0.768\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.640 \\-0.600 \\ 0.480\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\\
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.096 \\ 0.360 \\ 0.928\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.872 \\-0.480 \\ 0.096\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\qquad
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.096 \\ 0.360 \\ 0.928\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.480 \\ 0.800 \\-0.360\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\\
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.096 \\ 0.480 \\ 0.872\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.360 \\ 0.800 \\-0.480\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\qquad
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.152 \\ 0.480 \\ 0.864\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.864 \\ 0.360 \\-0.352\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\\
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.152 \\ 0.480 \\ 0.864\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.480 \\-0.800 \\ 0.360\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\qquad
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.168 \\ 0.224 \\ 0.960\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.576 \\ 0.768 \\-0.280\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\\
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.168 \\ 0.576 \\ 0.800\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.224 \\ 0.768 \\-0.600\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\qquad
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.192 \\ 0.480 \\ 0.856\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.744 \\-0.640 \\ 0.192\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\\
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.192 \\ 0.480 \\ 0.856\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.640 \\ 0.600 \\-0.480\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\qquad
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.192 \\ 0.640 \\ 0.744\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.480 \\ 0.600 \\-0.640\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\\
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.352 \\ 0.360 \\ 0.864\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.360 \\ 0.800 \\-0.480\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
\qquad
\left\langle
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.424 \\ 0.480 \\ 0.768\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{r} 0.480 \\ 0.600 \\-0.640\end{array}\right)
\right\rangle=0
$$

There are even some three-dimensional orthonormal bases among these. Again with no zero entries, and variations of those below might be obtained from sign changes, permutations of the rows or columns, and transposition.

$$
\left(\begin{array}{r}
 0.024 &  0.768 & -0.640 \\
 0.640 &  0.480 &  0.600 \\
 0.768 & -0.424 & -0.480
\end{array}\right)
\qquad
\left(\begin{array}{r}
 0.096 &  0.872 &  0.480 \\
 0.360 & -0.480 &  0.800 \\
 0.928 &  0.096 & -0.360
\end{array}\right)
\\
\left(\begin{array}{r}
 0.152 &  0.864 & -0.480 \\
 0.480 &  0.360 &  0.800 \\
 0.864 & -0.352 & -0.360
\end{array}\right)
\qquad
\left(\begin{array}{r}
 0.192 &  0.744 &  0.640 \\
 0.480 & -0.640 &  0.600 \\
 0.856 &  0.192 & -0.480
\end{array}\right)
$$

All of the above was found with quite a bit of brute force enumeration, so there might be more elegant approaches to finding these results. I also might very well have made a mistake.

Comment: Seeing the one downvote, I can't help but wonder whether someone disagrees with *what* results I found, or rather with *how* I found them, or something else entirely. Or perhaps it's a remnant of some serial downvoting I recently received. A comment to clarify the situation would have been much appreciated…